# Format string does't match

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have one problem in my query and I don't see where the problem is. So the problem is when I run the query I get error like

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.
```

So far my query is here

```
SELECT rp.* 
FROM responsible_persons  rp
LEFT JOIN projects  p ON p.ProjectID = rp.ProjectID
WHERE rp.UserID = 195
AND (SYSDATE BETWEEN p.StartDate AND p.EndDate)
```

So far I try to convert StartDate and EndDate `to_date()` but still I have problem.
What is wrong here ? Where I made mistake ?

Comment: What is the datatype of `startDate`and `endDate`, and what do the values look like?

Comment: ştartDate and endDate is VARCHAR2

Comment: what is the format of the data inside the varchar2 columns `startDate` and `endDate` ?

Comment: Format is 'YYYY-MM-DD'

Comment: Others have provided legitimate fixes to your immediate problem, but allow me to point out (as others have mentioned) that it is a _very serious_ design flaw to store DATEs as VARCHAR2.  This should be corrected.  If you say "but this is an existing system" I'd reply "then your existing system has a serious bug that needs to be fixed, just like any other serious bug you find".

Comment: @EdStevens I understand the problem, but unfortunetlly I didnt design database and it's not my mistake. But I have to check all tables and see If all Date filed as set up as VARCHAR2, but as far as I know it is, since in  a couple of tables I have also same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the NLS_DATE_FORMAT in your session to the values in your table, that sysdate can get the same format as the data you have there:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD' ;

SELECT rp.* 
FROM responsible_persons  rp
LEFT JOIN projects  p ON p.ProjectID = rp.ProjectID
WHERE rp.UserID = 195
AND (SYSDATE BETWEEN p.StartDate AND p.EndDate)
```

An example

```
SQL> create table t ( c1 varchar2(20) , c2 varchar2(20) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values ( '22.01.2020 10:00:00' , '22.01.2020 21:00:00' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t where ( sysdate between c1 and c2 ) ;
select * from t where ( sysdate between c1 and c2 )
                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month


SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'  ;

Session altered.

SQL> select * from t where ( sysdate between c1 and c2 ) ;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't store dates as strings.
Now, having said that, you would want to change your code to

```
AND (SYSDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(p.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE(p.EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

But understand that if p.EndDate is '2020-08-28' and SYSDATE is 2020-08-28 07:49:30, then you won't get a match because your date strings don't contain the time component that SYSDATE contains. So you might also want to strip the time component off of SYSDATE with this

```
TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

As suggested by Roberto, you could manipulate the NLS_DATE_FORMAT for your session to get past this problem.  But if you have other dates stored as strings and they aren't in the same format, then you've just pushed another problem onto the stack.